# What does views_ensure_table() do?

Tags: views

I see it often, $this->ensure_my_table() and I'm not sure what it does and why it is important when building Views handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the API page:

[views_handler::ensure_my_table](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!handlers.inc/function/views_handler%3a%3aensure_my_table/7)

> Ensure the main table for this handler is in the query. This is used a
>   lot.

It's just to make sure that the base table (`node` or `user` for example) that your handler needs is referenced in the query/actually exists.